# Fwrite only outputs files below the 143.4kb, does fwrite allow for more?

Tags: c++, fwrite

I need to create a binary file with only zeroes in it. At the moment, I was able to do it for 1kb. But I need one of 2mb. Is this possible or am I missing something or using fwrite incorrectly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    FILE *fileAux;
    fileAux = fopen("disk.dk","w+b");

    fwrite("0",1024,1024*2,fileAux);
    fclose(fileAux);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Giving `fwrite` a pointer to just two characters but then claiming that the pointer points to 1024 characters: that's not going to work, nope.

Comment: You can create a buffer of, for example, `1 KB`, using `char buffer[1024] = {0}`, which will initialize it to zero, and then you can call `fwrite( buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fileAux );` in a loop. For every loop iteration, it will write `1 KB` of zeroes. So, if you loop `10` times, it will write `10 KB` of zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

Buffer you are passing to it contains only 2 bytes. So you get a classical buffer overrun.